# How to work with time series data in predicting long-term unemployment?

Tags: r, time-series, random-forest, panel-data, prediction

So I am very new to both R and data science and have plunged myself into quite a project. I have also never worked with time series data - but I really wanted to learn something, which I hopefully will by this :)

**Population and research question** My population is people who have received public unemployment benefits in 2010-2015, and I would like to predict who of the unemployed who will become long-term-unemployed. So it concerns 'if' they become long-term unemployed, rather than 'when will they become long-term-unemployed'. I plan on using logistic regression, classification trees and random forest.

**Data structure** The type of benefit they receive is marked by a code every week in a year, so there is a column from year 2010 week 1 to year 2015 week 52. I would like to have a binary dependent variable for either being 'long-term-unemployed' (12 months or more), or 'not being long-term unemployed'. I plan on doing that by generating a variable that counts the number of consecutive weeks of receiving a benefit in 2010-2015, and if a person receives a benefit in this period, they will get assigned '1'. If not - '0'.

My independent variables are i.e. industry, education, age, gender, relationship status, income, and county. Some of this might also change over the course of 2010-2015, so at the moment they are represented by a column for each year, i.e. industry2010, industry 2011 etc.

**My question** My main concern is, how exactly to go about prepping my data for modeling. If I just keep the independent variables as they are at the moment, I assume they will not have much predictive value, as they are not tied to the employment status. Your industry in 2013 will not be of much predictive value if your long-term-unemployment period was 2010-2012.

How would you handle a problem like this, and is there any way I can scope my research question to make my data modeling less complicated? Let me know if I need to elaborate :)

Below is an example of what my data looks like. In the y2012_w - columns, the value just represents a certain type of benefit.

[image: See an example of thee data structure here. When it says N/A in the year-columns, it means that people are employed, and the codes are different types of benefits]

Comment: (1) To get started, use the past to predict the future. Predict $y_t$ using a vector $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}$. (2) What does 23 in column 2012_w1 mean?

Comment: That makes sense!
It is a code representing a certain type of benefit.